# Cache selected elements of an std::array and keep it consistent automatically in c++

Tags: c++, caching, stdarray

I have many instances of classes in an std::array. Based on a criteria I would like to select a few and store pointers to them in a separate array - a cache basically. I plan to use that 'cache' array to quickly iterate through the selection several times (maybe even in a separate thread using lock guards).

I would like to be able to remove and destruct instances from the original array and keep the cache array consistent.

Is there an elegant and automatic way to do this?

Comment: Flagged as _needs more focus_.

Comment: Depending on how far you want to go, non trivial. There are books written on the problem of cache coherency. For simple needs [look into `std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). Lot of overhead involved, though. For example, the primary array must contain `std::shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Thank you, that is good advice. It would solve the dangling pointer issue. I have not mentioned but I would like to use the cache in a time critical audio application so I am worried about calling std::weak_ptr.lock() to access the cached object. (Maybe even several hundred thousand times in a second.)

Comment: Have to test it to be sure, but you're justified in your worry. Off the top I can't think of anything I'd be comfortable suggesting at that access rate.

Answer (score 0):

Make the original array contain pointers to the objects.  Then, re-arranging that array will not change the actual objects.

Comment: What if I need to destruct objects?